# How to stop woocommerce session being destroyed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm hoping somebody can help.

I have a WordPress site running WooCommerce but every time somebody visits the homepage the session gets destroyed and thus the cart gets emptied.

This only happens on the homepage all other pages maintain the session absolutely fine.

When the session is destoryed and the cart is emptied, if I then add another product to the cart then all the cart contents from the previous session are still in there.

I'm wondering if there is any way to manually force the session to NOT be destroyed when visiting the homepage, i.e. unset the destroy session function.

WooCommerce version is 3.2.6.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question makes me wonder if you are simply just not starting `session_start()` on the homepage.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I've tested that already to no avail. Something is running later on and killing the session, I simply can't find the function that's doing it. Hence looking for a way to stop the session being killed.